# split column after nth character

Tags: sed, awk

I'm trying to split my second column in the file below after every 4 characters.

file.txt

```
>1A    THISISATEST
>1B    THATISATEST
```

desired output:

```
>1A    THIS    ISATEST
>1B    THAT    ISATEST
```

After searching and attempting to modify, I tried to use this sed command: `sed 's/(.{4})(.{7}).*/\2 \3/' file.txt`. However, I can't seem to get it to work. Am I missing something? However, if you have an `awk` suggestion, that would also be helpful. Also, please explain your suggestions. I'm in the learning process of `awk` and `sed`.

Comment: You just needed a `\ ` in front of each `{` and `}`. However, you should anchor the expression with `^` per jimmij's post. Otherwise, sed will match a random _set_ of 4 and then 7 characters.

Comment: Does the `awk` solution I gave works for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with `awk`. It separates first four characters and rest of the 2nd column into two variables and print them.

```
]$ awk '{s=substr($2,1,4)}{g=substr($2,5,length($2))}{print $1,s,g}' file.txt
1A THIS ISATEST
1B THAT ISATEST
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/^[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\{4\}/&\t/'
```

How it works:

- `^`: beginning of the line
- `[^ ]\+`: not space character matched at least one time
- `\+`: space character matched at least one time
- `[^ ]\{4\}`: not space character matched exactly four times
- `&`: everything matched between previous `//`
- `\t`: tab

Output:

```
>1A    THIS ISATEST
>1B    THAT ISATEST
```

---

Posixly correct:

```
sed 's/^[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ]\{4\}/&\t/'
```

The pattern `+` is GNU extension, so one need to simulate it with repeated character and a `*` to be posix compatible.

Comment: For some reason I can't get this to work appropriately.

Comment: The lines in my file actually start with a '>'. I will change my question

Comment: There is no error, but I am not getting the desired split. The file looks that same as the input

Comment: @stellar01 The `>` shouldn't change anything unless there are additional spaces after `>`. If you run example from the question with my command what is the output?

Comment: @stellar01 If you are on some *fancy* os like mac then it is possible that `sed` needs to be posixly correct - see the edit of my answer.

Comment: When I tried the example I posted, it did not work. I'll try the new suggestion

Comment: I am on fancy os. haha

Comment: The new suggestion seemed to work, but instead of printing a tab, a 't' was printed

Comment: @stellar01 - just use a literal *`<tab>`* character *(you can type one at your command prompt w/out the shell interfering like `CTRL+V` then `<tab>`)*. Alternatively - if your shell supports it - use `$'s/...\t.../'`. Or else: `t=$(printf \\t); sed "s/...${t}.../"` will also work.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/ [^ ]\{1,4\}/& /' <in >out
```

---

```
>1A    THIS ISATEST
```

---

It will work to insert a *<space>* after the longest match of the first occurrence of a sequence of 1 through 4 not-space characters immediately following a space character. This means that if the line starts with spaces it will affect the first not-space sequence *(which is arguably correct behavior)*, or else if the second space-separated column consists of four or fewer characters it will append an additional space to that column *(which is arguably incorrect behavior)*.

In no case does it substitute in a space for *every* fourth not-space character in the second column, though it does transform the example input to the example output.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `awk`

```
awk -F'\t' -vOFS='\t' '
  {patsplit($2, a, /.{4}/); 
   $2=""; for (k in a) $2=$2($2?"\t":"")a[k];  
   print}' file
```

Use `patsplit` to split the second field (`$2`) into 4 character chunks stored in array `a`. Join the chunks back with a tab separator and set into field 2 before printing out the record

```
1A    THIS  ISATEST
1B    THAT  ISATEST
```

Comment: What if you wanted to separate after more 4? Say like 90. Would I just have to add 90 dots?

Comment: @stellar01, take a look at my update

Comment: I get an error: `invalid -v option`

Comment: @stellar01, you're probably using a very basic version of `awk` in that case

Answer (score 0):

With **GNU awk** you can use `FPAT`

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS='\t' FPAT='>..\\s+\\w{4}|\\w*$'
```

- expression `>..\\s+\\w{4}` match to `>1A    THIS` and `\\w*$` match to the rest of string.
- `$1=$1` forces to output string with new separator `OFS`
- `1` is substitute for `{print $0}`